# powershell script: remove " " quotation marks around csv outputted file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to remove quotation marks around in my csv output file, but the code is not working. I followed the guidelines provided but still its not removing the quotation marks.

```
$OutFile = "C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\AoN Project\Execute\$([Environment]::MachineName).txt"  
$Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags"
Del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$RootPath = "C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\Operations Orchestration"

$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

$isInherited = @{
 $true  = 'Inherited'
 $false = 'Not Inherited'
}

$inheritance = @{
 0 = 'files only'
 1 = 'this folder and subfolders'
 2 = 'this folder and files'
  3 = 'subfolders and files'
}

$fldr = $Folder.FullName

$Folders | % {
$fldr = $_.FullName
Get-Acl $fldr | select -Expand Access |
 select @{n='Account';e={$_.IdentityReference}},
     @{n='Ace String';e={"{0} {1}, {2} ({3})" -f $_.AccessControlType,
       $_.FileSystemRights, $inheritance[$_.InheritanceFlags],
       $isInherited[$_.IsInherited]}},
    @{n='Object Path';e={$fldr}} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ascii | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File $OutFile -Force -Encoding ascii
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Export-Csv` is going to put the quotes right back into the file if it sees a string. Your best bet is to use `Out-File` to actually write the CSV.

This should replace your code:

```
@{n='Object Path';e={$fldr}} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File $OutFile -Force -Encoding ascii -Append
```

Comment: I changed it to that but the " " marks are still there:{ (Get-Content $OutFile) | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file -FilePath $OutFile -Force -Encoding ascii}

Comment: Changed what? That should be an additional line after the line you provided.

Comment: sorry I misread thought you had said replace anyways I have added it below the line i provided, but the output is still the same...

Comment: Edited the answer, this should replace your line of code entirely.

Comment: Sounds like you're not showing your full code, so it's hard to anticipate what you're looking at. If you're only getting headers that could indicate an empty object. If you are seeing the headers and a single line of data you might have to add the `-Append` switch to the `Out-File` section.

Comment: I have edited my question with the full code, can you spot anything? that needs changing as well?

Comment: Were you getting any errors? When I run your full code I got an error on the `-Encoding` parameter on `ConvertTo-Csv`. I've removed that now, and your code as a whole seems to be working for me.

Comment: You also will need the `-Append` switch at the end of that line, otherwise you'll overwrite your headers created in line 4.

Comment: Thank you very much this has fixed it, can i ask another q if you dont mind.I want the output (in the file to write on the same line instead of starting a new line run starting a new line) so from this [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,Allow FullControl (Inherited),C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\Operations Orchestration\Central
BUILTIN\Administrators,Allow FullControl,  (Inherited),C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\Operations Orchestration\Central] to this [Everyone Allow  Modify, this folder, subfolders and files (Inherited) \\UKSHEFAPXO\e$\Data\Global\PHE test cases\back up of phe\Test cases\Benefit statements]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. It's probably better to create a new question at this point, as this doesn't sound very straightforward.